# XPages: How to add a builder to an eclipse plugin project to build an XPage or custom control

Tags: plugins, xpages, controls

I am building an XSP Plugin Project using Domino Designer which works fine after I followed the steps of https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/1934D011E867500185257EF10064C5AA&SessionID=D4TCTAVUQ2 on how to create such a project.

This project includes custom controls also, which I cannot edit with the graphical designer, this is ok for me. My problem now is, that, when I edit a custom control with the text-editor, the corresponding java file does not get re-compiled. What I am currently doing is editing the XPage in a temp. NSF and copy back the .xsp AND the .java file to the plugin project, customizing some path´s...this is a pain.

[image: Project structure]

The .xsp-config file points to the location of the .java file in the project:
/com/adpunctum/aivistox/xsp/customcontrols/CCCategoryPicker

I added some builders form an NSF project and copied them to the .project file of the plugin-project.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
 <name>com.adpunctum.aivistox.xsp</name>
 <comment></comment>
 <projects>
 </projects>
 <buildSpec>  
  <buildCommand>
      <name>com.ibm.designer.domino.javalib.javalibmarkerbuilder</name>
      <arguments/>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>com.ibm.designer.domino.design.jsvalidationbuilder</name>
      <arguments/>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources.facesConfigbuilder</name>
      <arguments/>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources.BuildPropertiesBuilder</name>
      <arguments/>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources.pluginXMLbuilder</name>
      <arguments/>
    </buildCommand>   
    <buildCommand>
      <name>com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editor.xpagesbuilder</name>
      <arguments/>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
      <arguments/>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources.LWPDBuilder</name>
      <arguments/>
    </buildCommand>   
    <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.pde.ManifestBuilder</name>
      <arguments/>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.pde.SchemaBuilder</name>
      <arguments/>
    </buildCommand>
 </buildSpec>
 <natures>
  <nature>org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature</nature>
  <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
 </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Does anyone have the clue how to get these java files complied ?

Comment: Please add the code snippets rather than the images or screen shots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David, thank you for your hint - I just watched the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4Rn_3Bmy0M
At the end of the show, he tells a very basic and - for me - **important thing**: If you want to change something, just "copy back the important files to the osgi plugin"...well, it seems that this is the **only solution** how to make changes in such a plugin: edit the custom controls in an .nsf project and **copy the files to the plugin**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but maybe the [XPagesDesignerPlugin4Eclipse project in OpenNTF Stash](https://stash.openntf.org/projects/XDPE/repos/xpagesdesignerplugin4eclipse/browse?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fdevelop) may point you in the right direction. Christian Guedemann was involved in the development of it, so may be able to advise.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for the hint, I will have a look on it and post back the next days after trying it...or, maybe, get in contact with the person you mentioned!

Comment: There's been a couple NotesIn9 shows on creating custom renderers/global custom controls.  Maybe there's something in there that would be helpful.